# Context data passing variants which is a reference to another entity

Tags: localization, l20n

Legend: {} is context data; <> is a l20n entity.

======================================

(1) [Passing a variant](http://l20n.org/learn/using-external-variables-in-translations/).  I understand this.

```
{
  "user": "Jane"
}
<liked "{{ $user }} liked your post.">
```

Result: Jane liked your post.

======================================

(2) In one entity, [reference to](http://l20n.org/learn/working-with-text-multiline-interpolation/) another entity.  I understand this.

```
{
  "user": "Jane"
}
<liked "{{ $user }} liked your post: {{ postname }}.">
<postname "Post with a very long name">
```

Result: Jane liked your post: Post with a very long name.

======================================

### (3) Question: How to do this?

```
{
  "gender": "M"
}
<genderIs "Gender is {{ $gender }}.">
<M "male">
<F "female">
```

Wanted Result: Gender is male.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by L20n and we don't have any immediate plans to add this feature.  I'd like to suggest a different approach.  We've found that it serves the purpose well and also helps to keep the translations atomic and defined in one place.

```
{
  "gender": "M"
}

<genderIs[$gender] {
  M: "Gender is male.",
  F: "Gender is female."
}>
```